# To check if input is over in python

Tags: python, dictionary, input

So, i have this dictionary where in i have to store some names and numbers which are given as input and after that i have to check if the given name is in the dictonary , if yes than i should print that name and its corresponding phone number value , this i should do till the input is not over ....I think i'm doing it wrongly , can anyone suggest me how to terminate the loop once user input is over ...

I tried using a try except block but it fails, as it doesn't stop taking input once the input is over ...I have problem that once input is taken and it is checked that dictionary has that key: value pair , it should check for another input , if no input is there it should terminate the loop , but it still keeps going . Below is the code i was using ...

`Q = []
while True:
    try:
        Q.append(input())
    except EOFError:
        break`

I expect that once user input is stopped ,while loop should automatically stop ,like if input is

`sam 123
 tom 321
john 345(last input)`

after last input the while block should stop and control should go to next statement , but it fails and again nd again it prompts for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate the input in the while loop.

```
while input():
    print("still inputting")
```

this will break the loop when the input is empty, (when the return button is pressed whit out any input)